# Когда я ставлю в ImageView картинку, она выглядит как точка

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Здравствуйте задам вопрос по другому. И так, я взял фото

[image]
[image]

и переместил в папку C:\Users\TokaeV\AndroidStudioProjects\RAEK Prog\app\src\main\res\drawable. Далее создал activity и туда добавил ImageView, сразу в открывшемся окошке выбрал фото из той папки.
Вот как он у меня отображается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Увеличивать тоже не получается, даже точка исчезает.
Сам нигде код не писал.
Это код активити

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_Raspisanie_P-23"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="142dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="143dp" />
```

Comment: Покажите код и разметку. По приведённому вами описанию проблемы сказать ничего нельзя.

Comment: В коде я ничего не писал. Я просто добавил ImageView и далее я вверху уже написал

Comment: Тогда покажите разметку

Comment: Всю разметку покажите

Comment: А что означает _при ее увеличивание_ - `ImageView` ведь этого не умеет из коробки? И как мы узнаем, правильно ли Вы делаете, если мы не видим как Вы это делаете?

Comment: Так подскажите как вы именно делаете?

Comment: Вообще превью студии не эталон и не всё может корректно отобразить - проверять нужно на устройствах/эмуляторах. У Вас там маячит предупреждение (красный кружок с **!** ) - посмотрите что он хочет.

Answer (score 1):

Наконец то я понял. Тем у кого так же, уберите из названия картинки тире нижнее тире и другие символы. Мне помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас проблема с разрешением картинки, у `ImageView` есть свойство `scaleType` установите например:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/tree"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Параметр `fitXY` подстроит масштаб под параметры `ImageView`, а вообще рекомендую почитать, [наглядная статья](http://androiddocs.ru/atribut-scaletype-dlya-imageview/)

Comment: Я скопировал твой код, все осталось так же. Может мне размер изображения поменять или что то другое?

Comment: какой размер изображения?